# Semaphores and locks in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, semaphore, race-condition

I am working on a MATLAB project where I would like to have two instances of MATLAB running in parallel and sharing data. I will call these instances `MAT_1` and `MAT_2`. More specifically, the architecture of the system is:

1. `MAT_1` processes images sequentially, reading them one by one using `imread`, and outputs the result for each image using `imwrite`.
2. `MAT_2` reads the images output by `MAT_1` using `imread` and outputs its result somewhere else.

One of the problems I think I need to address is to guarantee that `MAT_2` reads an image output by `MAT_1` once `MAT_1` has fully finished writing to it.

My questions are:

1. How would you approach this problem? Do I need to use semaphores or locks to prevent race conditions?
2. Does MATLAB provide any mechanism to lock files? (i.e. something similar to [`flock`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/flock.1.html), but provided by MATLAB directly, and that works on multiple platforms, e.g. Windows & Linux). If not, do you know of any third-party library that I can use to build this mechanism in MATLAB?

#### EDIT :

- As @yoda points out below, the Parallel Computing Toolbox (PCT) allows for blocking calls between MATLAB workers, which is great. That said, I am particularly interested in solutions that do not require the PCT.
- Why do I require `MAT_1` and `MAT_2` to run in parallel threads?:

  The processing done in `MAT_2` is slower on average (and more prone to crashing) than `MAT_1`, and the output of `MAT_1` feeds other programs and processes (including human inspection) that do not need to wait for `MAT_2` to do its job.

#### Answers :

- For a solution that allows for the implementation of semaphores but does not rely on the PCT see Jonas' answer below
- For other good approaches to the problem, see Yoda's answer below

Comment: @DustyCampbell, I'm guessing the OP wants poor man's parallelization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I'd use the parallel processing toolbox for this.

As far as I know, there is no straightforward way in Matlab to have systemwide file locks. However, in order to ensure that Matlab #2 only reads output of Matlab #1 when the file has finished writing, I suggest that after writing e.g the file `results_1.mat`, Matlab #1 writes a second file, `results_1.finished`, which is an empty text file. Since the second file is written after the first, its existence signals that the results-file has been written. You can thus search for files with the extension `finished`, i.e. `dir('*.finished')`, and use `fileparts` to get the name of the .mat file you'd like to load with Matlab #2.

Comment: Thanks @Jonas. That's a good idea, and I thought about that, but I was wondering if there was something else out there. I have used the PCT before, and as far as I remember, this is not something they support directly; I haven't seen anything in the PCT that supports signaling between running MATLAB processes. IIRC most of what the PCT supports is asynchronous and synchronous execution of MATLAB functions and scripts, and it typically requires full data or task parallelism.

Comment: Yes, the parallel processing toolbox won't have two Matlab sessions communicate with one another. What I'd probably do is either do all #1 in parallel, and then all #2 in parallel, or modify the code so that my `parfor` loop does first one step of #1 and then the corresponding #2.

Comment: Thanks @Jonas. I'm accepting this answer because it fits more closely to what I was asking for. It allows me to build locks without using the PCT.

Comment: @AmV: Just curious as to how you implemented a file block with this solution, as I might need to use it too. Also, if you do `dir('filename')` when matlab #1 is still running, won't there be missing files from what hasn't been run? In that case you might have to run dir each time and check for newer files, no?

Comment: @doob, You can do this with MATLAB [timers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/timer.html). You can have `MAT_2` check every few seconds for new **.finished** files using `dir('*.finished')` as @Jonas suggested.

Comment: This approach seems risky in that you're relying on certain semantics of the file system.  If MAT_1 perceives the order of operations in the file system as ("write last byte of image1", "create image1.finished") - MAT_2 may not be guaranteed to perceive those operations in the same order.

Answer (score 8):

I would approach this using semaphores; in my experience the PCT is unreasonably slow at synchronization.

dfacto (another answer) has a great implementation of semaphores for MATLAB, however it will not work on MS Windows; I improved on that work so that it would.  The improved work is here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45504-semaphoreposixandwindows

This will be better performing than interfacing with Java, .NET, the PCT, or file locks. This does not use the Parallel Computing Toolbox (PCT), and AFAIK semaphore functionality isn't in the PCT anyway (puzzling that they left it out!).  It is possible to use the PCT for synchronization but everything I'd tried in it was unreasonably slow.

To install this high-performance semaphore library into MATLAB, run this within the MATLAB interpreter:
mex -O -v semaphore.c

You'll need a C++ compiler installed to compile semaphore.c into a binary MEX-file. That MEX-file is then callable from your MATLAB code as shown in the example below.

Usage example:

```
function Example()
    semkey=1234;
    semaphore('create',semkey,1);
    funList = {@fun,@fun,@fun};
    parfor i=1:length(funList)
        funList{i}(semkey);
    end
end
function fun(semkey)
    semaphore('wait',semkey)
    disp('hey');
    semaphore('post',semkey)
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you are looking for matlab-only solution but I have just submitted a semaphore wrapper for use in Matlab.  It works as a generic semaphore, but it was mainly designed with [sharedmatrix](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28572-sharedmatrix) in mind.

As soon as Mathworks accepts the submission, I will update the link on my research group's [blog](http://smlv.cc.gatech.edu/2011/08/10/semaphores-in-matlab/).

Please note that this mex file is a wrapper for the POSIX semaphore functionality.  As such it will work in Linux, Unix, MacOS but will not work out-of-the-box on Windows.  It may work when compiled against cygwin libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is a fool-proof way other than using the OS specific locks. One approach might be to have MAT_1 do:

```
imwrite(fileName);
movefile(fileName, completedFileName);
```

And have MAT_2 only process completedFileName.

Comment: Thanks @Ashish. This is an interesting idea, but are move operations atomic in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

#### EDIT:

After seeing your edit, a simple solution not involving the use of any toolboxes is the following:

Since `MAT_2` is much slower than `MAT_1`, start `MAT_2` with a delay. i.e., start it when `MAT_1` has finished processing say 5 images or so. If you do this, `MAT_2` will never catch up with `MAT_1` and hence will never be in a situation where it has to "wait" for images from `MAT_1`.

---

I'm still not clear on a few things from your question:

1. You say `MAT_1` processes images sequentially, but *does it have to*? In other words, does the order in which they are processed matter?
2. You say `MAT_2` reads the output from `MAT_1`... Does it have to be in the order that `MAT_1` finishes or can that be any order?
3. You say `MAT_2` reads the image using `imread` and outputs it some where else. Is there any reason that task cannot be combined into `MAT_1`?

In any case, you can implement some form of execution blocking using the parallel computing toolbox; but instead of using `parfor` loops (which is what most people use), you'll have to create a distributed job ([example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/bq5ntwk.html)).

The important thing to note is that each worker (lab) has a [`labindex`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/labindex.html), and you can use [`labSend`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/labsend.html) to send data from worker 1 (equivalent of `MAT_1`) to worker 2 (equivalent of `MAT_2`), who then receives it using [`labReceive`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/labreceive.html). From the documentation on `labReceive`:

> This function blocks execution in the lab until the corresponding call to labSend occurs in the sending lab.

which is pretty much what you wanted to do with `MAT_1` and `MAT_2`.

Another way to do this would be to spawn one additional worker in your current session, but only assign tasks performed by `MAT_1` to it. You then set the [`FinishedFcn`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/toolbox/distcomp/finishedfcn.html) property for the tasks to execute the set of functions performed by `MAT_2`, but I wouldn't recommend it as I don't think this was the intent for `FinishedFcn`, and I don't know if it will break in certain cases.

Comment: Thanks @yoda. I might be wrong but I think the last time I used the PCT, it didn't have anything such as `labsend` and `labreceive`. That definitely helps! As for why I require `MAT_1` and `MAT_2` to run in parallel threads, the processing done in `MAT_2` is much slower than that of `MAT_1`, and the output of `MAT_1` feeds other programs and processes (including human inspection) that do not _need_ to wait for `MAT_2` to do its job. In any case, and to clarify (I"ll put it on the original post), I'm particularly interested in solutions that do not require a PCT license.

Comment: @AmV: You are correct in that PCT and DCT (distributed computing toolbox) used to be different, but now they've been merged into one. I guess I'll wait for your edit, as more info will certainly be helpful.

Comment: @AmV: Please see my edit for a simpler solution that does not involve any toolbox.

Comment: labSend and labReceive were first implemented in R14-sp3 (if memory serves...). However, the `spmd` keyword makes things more convenient. One thing to remember - if your processes are on different hosts, there may be some lag before updates to the filesystem are visible...

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend to look at the parallel processing toolbox for such a thing, the functionality you want should be in there somewhere. I think it's cleaner that way than trying to synchronize two instances of MATLAB (unless you are forced to use two instances).

In the odd case that there is no such thing, you might also look at different environments to implement what you want. It might be a bit of a workaround, but you can always interface your MATLAB code with other languages (e.g. Java, .NET, C, ...) and use the functionality you are accustomed to there. With Java you are quite sure that your solution is platform independent, .NET only works on Windows (at least in combination with MATLAB).