# Force parfor to respect some order

Tags: matlab, parfor

I understand that some indeterminism stems from `parfor`'s parallel nature but I don't understand why it should be entirely random. Is there any way to force `parfor` to respect (at least loosely) the order of the loop? More specifically I would like that in the case of:

```
parfor i=1:100
    do_independent_stuff()
end
```

each worker of the pool when asking for a new task (i.e. in this case a new iteration of the loop) to be affected the lowest i that hasn't been computed or affected to a worker yet.

Answer (score 4):

I think its by design that running something in parallel assumes that order is not important, at least in Matlab. Each thread/worker should be independent of each other. However, as indicated in this [question](http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/answers/65350-why-does-parfor-execute-loops-in-a-random-order), you could try  [job and task control](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/distcomp/index.html#) interface to give you some level of control.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I still don't understand why Matlab decided not to follow at all the loop order (OK it's not random). Some other libraries like [Python's multiprocessing pool.map](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-Python-equivalent-of-MATLABs-parfor?share=1) do respect the order (obviously minus the indeterminism caused by parallelization). Good to know about the job and task control interface!

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, in practice, `PARFOR` isn't "entirely random" - you can easily observe that it sends out chunks of loop iterates in reverse order. In R2013b and later, if you need more control over ordering (if, for example, you know that certain of your independent things are likely to  take a long time, and therefore wish to start computing them first), you can use [`PARFEVAL`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfeval.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you need to loosely synchronize things, for instance wait until some thread as finished or has reach some point before to start another one, best should be to use semaphores, locks, mutex, etc...

I don't know if 'Parallel toolbox' includes such synchronization objects, but here is some workaround to create semaphore for instance:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22874669/684399

You can also use objects in 'System.Threading' namespace (requires .NET):

Init:

```
someResultAvailable = System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false);
```

In some job:

```
... do work ...
someResultAvailable .Set();
... continue ...
```

In another one:

```
... do work ...
if (!someResultAvailable.WaitOne(10000))
{
    error('Timeout waiting for result from other thread');
}
... continue now knowing that results are available ...
```