# Avoiding race conditions when using parfor in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, concurrency, parallel-processing

I'm looping in parallel and changing a variable if a condition is met. Super idiomatic code that I'm sure everyone has written a hundred times:

```
trials = 100;
greatest_so_far = 0;
best_result = 0;

for trial_i = 1:trials
    [amount, result] = do_work();

    if amount > greatest_so_far
        greatest_so_far = amount;
        best_result = result;
    end
end
```

If I wanted to replace `for` by `parfor`, how can I ensure that there aren't race conditions when checking whether we should replace `greatest_so_far`? Is there a way to lock this variable outside of the check? Perhaps like:

```
trials = 100;
greatest_so_far = 0;
best_result = 0;

parfor trial_i = 1:trials
    [amount, result] = do_work();

    somehow_lock(greatest_so_far);
    if amount > greatest_so_far
        greatest_so_far = amount;
        best_result = result;
    end
    somehow_unlock(greatest_so_far);
end
```

Comment: This link might help, it looks like you can use a mutex in matlab. I have no experience with it, but I think this is what you want. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/22180-timers-and-thread-safety

Comment: Thanks BumSkeeter, I'll see what I can do with it

Comment: +1 for well written question

Comment: I don't think you can do this with 'parfor'. With parfor your loops must be independent, and the way you have written your loop, they are not independent as greatest_so_far depends on the results from other iterations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skewed answer. It does not exactly solve your problem, but it might help you avoiding it.

If you can afford the memory to store the outputs of your `do_work()` in some vectors, then you could simply run your `parfor` on this function only, store the result, then do your scoring at the end (outside of the loop):

```
amount = zeros( trials , 1 ) ;
result = zeros( trials , 1 ) ;

parfor trial_i = 1:trials
    [amount(i), result(i)] = do_work();
end

[ greatest_of_all , greatest_index ] = max(amount) ;
best_result = result(greatest_index) ;
```

---

**Edit/comment** : (*wanted to put that in comment of your question but it was too long, sorry*).
I am familiar with `.net` and understand completely your *lock/unlock* request. I myself tried many attempts to implement a kind of progress indicator for very long `parfor` loop ... to no avail.

If I understand Matlab [classification of variable](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/advanced-topics.html#bq_of7_-1) correctly, the mere fact that you assign `greatest_so_far` (in `greatest_so_far=amount`) make Matlab treat it as a *temporary* variable, which will be cleared and reinitialized at the beginning of every loop iteration (hence unusable for your purpose).

So an easy locked *variable* may not be a concept we can implement simply at the moment. Some convoluted class event or file writing/checking may do the trick but I am afraid the timing would suffer greatly. If each iteration takes a long time to execute, the overhead might be worth it, but if you use `parfoor` to accelerate a high number of short execution iterations, then the convoluted solutions would slow you down more than help ...

You can have a look at this stack exchange question, you may find something of interest for your case: [Semaphores and locks in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415283/semaphores-and-locks-in-matlab)

Comment: I also thought of this solution. It is less desirable because it requires storing all of the results, but it does the trick nonetheless. If no one else comes along I'll accept this answer.

Comment: After the very lucid "It does not exactly solve your problem, but it might help you avoiding it" you already had my +1 :-)

Answer (score 2):

The solution from Hoki is the right way to solve the problem as stated. However, as you asked about race conditions and preventing them when loop iterations depend on each other you might want to investigate [`spmd` and the various `lab*` functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/task-control-and-worker-communication.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use SPMD to do this - SPMD allows communication between the workers. Something like this:

```
bestResult = -Inf;
bestIndex  = NaN;
N = 97;
spmd
  % we need to round up the loop range to ensure that each
  % worker executes the same number of iterations
  loopRange = numlabs * ceil(N / numlabs);
  for idx = 1:numlabs:loopRange
    if idx <= N
      local_result = rand(); % obviously replace this with your actual function
    else
      local_result = -Inf;
    end
    % Work out which index has the best result - use a really simple approach
    % by concatenating all the results this time from each worker
    % allResultsThisTime will be 2-by-numlabs where the first row is all the
    % the results this time, and the second row is all the values of idx from this time
    allResultsThisTime = gcat([local_result; idx]);
    % The best result this time - consider the first row
    [bestResultThisTime, labOfBestResult] = max(allResultsThisTime(1, :));
    if bestResultThisTime > bestResult
      bestResult = bestResultThisTime;
      bestIndex  = allResultsThisTime(2, labOfBestResult);
    end
  end
end
disp(bestResult{1})
disp(bestIndex{1})
```